# sharepoint 2016 workflow error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer-workflow

below is what the URL log is telling me my error is but i cant figure it out any help would be very much appreciated
`Microsoft.Workflow.Client.InternalServerException: Exception thrown from the data layer. For more details, please see the server logs. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId: ec23db4e-541a-46d8-a4b9-10cfdb36cc3b. NodeId: SHAREPOINTSITE. Scope: /SharePoint/default/a59b336d-2b82-4a00-a7b8-2de1b84af71c. Client ActivityId : f255c49f-033a-c062-2721-4ee6b1171a38. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.`

````
at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult result)    
at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)     -
-- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)    
at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowManagementClient.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)    
at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ScopeManager.PublishScopeInternal(ScopeDescription description, String[] pathSegments)    
at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ScopeManager.PublishChildScope(String childScopeName, ScopeDescription description)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.SPWebWorkflowSecurityContext.CreateServiceGroup(String scopeAddress, ScopeDescription serviceGroup)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.SPWebWorkflowSecurityContext.CreateOrUpdateServiceGroup(SPWeb lookupWeb, SPAppPrincipal app) StackTrace: 
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (sig=5fa0e72f-c37c-49be-8b42-b95544077530|2|microsoft.office.server.native.pdb, offset=28719)
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (offset=2EAF6)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Can you build the workflow but cannot publish it?

If yes, please grant permission of workflow manager service account in "**WF_InstanceManagement_DB**" and "**WF_ResourceManagement_DB**".

After granting the permission, SharePoint 2013 workflow can run.

Here is a similar case for your reference:

- **[SP Designer 2013 - Workflow internal server error when publishing](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2575c032-840a-440b-8c60-84457648f007/sp-designer-2013-workflow-internal-server-error-when-publishing?forum=sharepointcustomization)**